# In D8 How to ignore other duplicate value and merge multi-term value field while importing using csv file?

Tags: csv, import, migration, drupal-8, import-csv

In d8 I am importing the csv file data to the content type and I have csv file some thing like this.

```
id,node_title,multi_term,status
===============================
1,testing title,term_A,1
1,testing title,term_B,1
1,testing title,term_C,1
1,testing title,term_D,1
1,testing title,term_E,1
===============================
```

and my yml file is some thing like this

```
id: importing_content
class: null 
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: null
label: 'Import Content Type Story'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: story.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  delimiter: ','
  keys:
    - id
process:
  nid: id
  title: node_title
  tag_term:
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: taxonomy_migration
      no_stub: true
      source: multi_term 
  status: status
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: content_type
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies: null
```

with this configuration I am successfully importing the csv file but this will ignores the duplicate id's rows and all its value also.

my expected result is to ignore all the duplicate column of having same `id`  but update the unique value of column `multi_term` with comma on the   `content type field` which is of type `multiple value term reference field`.

any help will appreciated,
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using an `entity_generate` plugin which comes with [migrate_plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus) module.

But be aware that entities created as side effects with `entity_generate`, which means they are not rolled back - because they don't have a migration of their own, they are not tracked in a migration map table.

This is the main disadvantage of using `entity_generate`, versus migrating all entities in their own migrations, which is the recommended approach where practical.

Comment: thanks for reply, But I achieve it by modify the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The source plugin uses the list values in keys to identify an individual row.

If you have multiple values to make a unique key, then add all of those columns as keys.  Depending on your values, you might add id,node_title,multi_term,status all as keys.